# Trying to use this "for loop" to create a dictionary with a csv file I parsed from a json file

Tags: python, dictionary

New to Python so thanks for the help/support.

I have been able to pull a salesforce report (json file) and parse the file.  The issue I am having is that I need to create a dictionary that will take each row and create a dictionary that will take all the rows in the file and make it into a dictionary like so:

m_account_number: case_number, report_label, report_id

I thought I could do this with the current "for loop" as you can see I put it at the bottom of the loop with 
blist["m_account_number"]["case_number"]["report_label"]["report_id"]

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

```
import csv

blist = {"m_account_number" :{"case_number", "report_label","report_id"}}

csv_file = open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

facts = parser.data["factMap"]["T!T"]["rows"]
for row in facts:
    data_cells = row['dataCells']
    case_owner = data_cells[0]['label']

    m_account_number = data_cells[1]['value']
    case_number = data_cells[2]['label']
    report_label = data_cells[3]['label']
    report_id  = data_cells[3]['value'] 

    csv_writer.writerow([
        case_owner,
        m_account_number,
        case_number,
        report_label,
        report_id,  
    ])
csv_file.close()

print(blist)
```

Comment: Where do you take this: `parser.data["factMap"]["T!T"]["rows"]`

Comment: `blist[m_account_number]=[case_number,report_label,report_id]` should work. I would use a list(`[..]`) for the values. As set(`{..}`) would remove any duplicate items and thus when `case_number==report_id` there would be an issue.

Comment: Parser is from a JSON file I get from Salesforce